# Necesito filtrar por rango de fechas en firebase con angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase

Este es mi código:

```
  //Abro la conexion con firebase y la referencia
angular.module('app',["firebase"])
.controller('appCtrl',function($scope,$firebase){
   var ref = new Firebase("https://nombreproyecto/BD");

 const boton = document.querySelector("#btn_filtrar");

// Agregar listener
boton.addEventListener("click", function(evento){
// Aquí todo el código que se ejecuta cuando se da click al botón


var fechaFiltroIn = document.getElementById("Fecha").value;

var sync = $firebase(ref.orderByChild('fechax').startAt(fechaFiltroIn).endAt(fechaFiltroFin));   
     $scope.DB = sync.$asArray();

});

//DatePicker  F Inicial
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#Fecha").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});

//Datepicker Fecha Final
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#FechaF").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());

});
```

[image: Anvu]
Todo funciona bien cuando es un mes pero existiendo registros de otro mes, me filtra lo de ambos meses y lo que quiero realizar es una consulta que me filtre los datos como deberian, lo que quiero es poderlos filtrar se que es por que no tengo el tipo de dato Date, para friltrar por eso necesito de su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes poner el código como *código*? Las imágenes son complicadas de ejecutar o depurar, el texto es mucho más sencillo. No añadas imágenes a las preguntas si no son sobre UI o gráficos

Comment: Listo ya agregue el codigo.